# Dedupe a character from the end of a string

Tags: ruby, string

I'd like to dedupe a specific character from the end of a string, just leaving one unique character at the end.

So I'd like the following to happen:

```
buns = "well, that was unusual....."
buns.dedupe(".")
#=> "well, that was unusual."
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One unique character in a sequence, or in the entire string? That is, what should happen to the string `".X."`? Should it yield `"X."` (leaving only 1 dot at the end) or just remain `".X."` as there is only one dot in a row?

Comment: You're just trying to get someone to type [`buns.squeeze`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-squeeze), aren't you? =P

Comment: This has been the greatest coincidence of my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to remove duplicate characters from the end of the string (as opposed to anywhere in the string, as `String#squeeze` does):

```
"well, that was unusual.....".gsub(/\.+$/, '.')
```